# BASH: Executing Gnuplot for multiple files

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I am trying to traverse through multiple sub directories in a main directory for each sub directory I want to load a  gnuplot script, after every .eps file in generated by the script copy them all into another directory, I am only getting the first file from the first directory, but not the rest.here is what i have:

```
file=graph.gp
path=/home/me/maindir/
for file in path; do
gnuplot <<- EOF
    load 'graph.gp'
EOF
done
find maindir/ -name "*.eps" exec cp -i {} -t /home/me/outputdir \;
```

Comment: What's the `$` doing on those first two lines? Shell variable assignment is `var=value` with no spaces around the `=`. You use `$` when getting the value of a variable. So `for file in $path`, etc. Without a glob `*`/etc. `for file in /home/me/maindir/` is going to only have one entry to loop over. Oh, also you haven't told us what problem you are actually having... aside from the syntax errors, etc. which I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for clarification I am very new to bash,this is the first time I am actually writing out bash scripts. I am not looping to every subdirectory only the first, I want to traverse  into every subdirectory in `maindir/` and run gnuplot to load the .eps file, then copy all '.eps' into another directory

Comment: Yes, you want to loop over every directory in `maindir` so you want `for file in /home/me/maindir/*` not `for file in /home/me/maindir`. Compare the output from `echo /home/me/maindir/` to `echo /home/me/maindir/*` for example.

Comment: when I run the script I receive the following error: `Cannot open 'graph.gp', line 0: util.c: No such file or directory`

Comment: Run what script? Not the one in your post. Update with your new script. Do you have such a file in every directory (assuming that's where they need to be)?

Comment: yes in every sub directory I have a file called 'graph.gp'

Comment: You aren't changing directories in your script. You are always calling `gnuplot` from the main directory. Do you need to change directory or use the full path to the `gp` file?

Comment: that must be the thing I am doing wrong, I am trying to go into every directory and run gnuplot from there, then do the same for the next etc...

Comment: `for file in path; do` will loop once and set `file` to `path`. You need `$path` to use the `path` variable and you still don't have a glob there so you will only get the top `maindir` path from that. You want `pushd "$file"; gnuplot; popd` (or similar) as the loop body.